# Adding prerequisite for msi in Installshield

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield

I would like to know if it is possible to add a prerequiste for a msi installer through Installshield. (Through this [link](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IDlgPrereqPropSettings.htm) looks as was possible)
I am able to build a exe that works properly, but if I try to get a msi installer I get the following error:

> -7067: Your project contains InstallShield prerequisites. A Setup.exe setup launcher is required if you are building a release that includes
>   InstallShield prerequisites. Change your release settings to build
>   Setup.exe, or remove the prerequisites from your project.

In the redistributables window I have added .NET 4.5 framework, and in its build location download from web. Anyway fails for msi in all the build locations

Comment: `Setup.exe setup launcher` is a must if you have added some prerequisites e.g. .Net framework 4.5 from `Installation Designer -> Application Data -> Redistributes ` in a basic MSI project. You won''t get an output if you have configured your project output either for `Single Executable` or `Single MSI Package`. Uncheck both the check-boxes for `Single Executable` and `Single MSI Package`on `Project Assistant` tab to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear in telling you what the problem is.  Your product configuration / release build settings are set for single MSI.  An MSI cannot install an MSI due to Windows Installer mutex constraints.  A bootstrapper (.exe) is required to install the prereq and then your MSI.  Change your build settings to EXE  and the error will go away.

Comment: So that mean we cannot create a .msi package in installshield for projects which have prerequisites.